# Dataframe creation with weekdays or adding week days

Tags: python, pandas

Is anyone know the fonction to create a dataframe only with week days ? (variant with open days)

And how to add week days to an existing dataframe ?

I only know this function to create a blank dataframe:

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'value' : zeros(10)}, index=pd.date_range(pd.datetime(2014,3,30), freq='D', periods=100))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use freq='B' (Business Day) in you daterange argument to get what you want, like so

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'value' : [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}, index=pd.date_range(pd.datetime(2014,3,30), freq='B', periods=10))
```